Kindly review schematics of BLE board using STM32Wb55RG
I'm new to emended system and PCB design. This will be my first PCB design.

Before moving to PCB design just want to confirm that my circuit will work. Kindly review schematics. Any Feedback is appreciated.
Im getting this error and warning in ERC.

Error: Input Power pin not driven by any output power pins
PIN 43 VLXSPMS
Error: Input Power pin not driven by any output Power pins
Pin 14 VDDA
Warning:

VDDA & VREF+ are attached to same items; VDDA will be used in netlist
VDD and VDDSMPS are attached to same items; VDD will be used in netlist
I have used AN5165 Application note Hardware guide from ST ,VFQFPN68 reference board
download Kicad file : KICAD FILE

What are the purpose of R1 and D1? Aren't they useless?


Regarding the violation errors, add a PWR_FLAG to those pins. 2) Same comment as Justme on R1 and D1, I don't know why STM recommend to have D1 though. 3) You don't need D2 as well as you already has U1. If you are new to PCB design, and yet you pick a RF project, I wish you luck...

